# Run chkdsk on a drive that is not recognized (not present in diskpart)

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, chkdsk

I have an SSD with damaged NTFS (probably due to the old age, although SMART doesn't mention "near failure" state anywhere and still gives it 31% or resource).

I was able to recover most of the stuff by cloning it (creating an image) under [Linux](https://www.system-rescue.org/) and using `testdisk`.
Some files are missing though.
I can see them with `ntfsls` (`ntfsprogs`) but I can't print them out (file system errors).

`ntfsprogs` also refuse to do any fix and recovery routines it supposedly provide, tells the disk is marked for `chkdsk` and recommends to do that first.

Now, if I try to connect this disk to a Windows machine or boot into Windows recovery mode and open the command prompt from there - I can't get any access to this disk - `diskpart` and `mountvol` don't mention it.

Is there anything left to try?
Either to persuade Windows to recognize this disk or to use some 3rd party tool that can do `chkdsk`'s job. Or maybe there is something else that can be done from Linux.

Comment: You don't want to be running any 'disk fixer' of any kind on a failing drive. You want to be copying off with dd & examining what manages to copy. The rest is now junk, or income for a data recovery company. The 'fix' for this is a reliable backup strategy… saves all this worry.

Comment: Back in the day we used SpinRite https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm but I don't think that will work for SSDs. There are many recovery tools but they all require the drive to be seen by the OS. If the OS can't see the device you need to contact a professional data recovery specialist.

Comment: I had found this:https://superuser.com/questions/518634/running-chkdsk-on-a-disk-partition-without-a-drive-letter, try the second answer, run chkdsk with hardware ID, and it should do the trick.

Comment: @xeнεi-Ξэnвϵς Nope, as I said, the disk is not present in `diskpart` and `mountvol` listings. Unsurprisingly, it also isn't mentioned in `diskmgmt.msc`. This means Windows gives up on it before Volume ID is assigned.

Comment: Then you are in a worse situation than I thought; Try hdwwiz.cpl and see if you can find your SSD, if you can find it, you should be able to find its hwid by yourself.

Comment: @xeнεi-Ξэnвϵς, Device Manager wasn't useful in this case either. I've additionally checked whether I can find it with [USB Device Tree Viewer](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html) and [USBLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html), but nothing there either. I think I also tried to have the disk inside the SATA slot while booting to recovery from USB, in order to exclude the possibility it isn't detected only via USB. Anyway, it's solved now. I'm only curious whether this disk will become visible again after format, but that's besides the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.
The key was to realize I don't have to run `chkdsk` on a physical disk.

#### 1. Create a disk image under Linux

I did this already but mention it here for completeness.

Depending on the nature of the failure, simply `dd` might work, or `ddrescue` might be needed instead.

#### 2. Convert raw image to VHD

This will allow to mount it under Windows.

Tools that can do this:

- `qemu-img`;
- `VBoxManage` from Oracle VirtualBox.

I'm using [qemu-img for Windows](https://cloudbase.it/qemu-img-windows/) with the following command:

```
.\qemu-img.exe convert -O vpc -p .\image.dd .\image.vhd
```

`-O vpc` sets the VHD output format. Use `-O vhdx` for VHDX.

`-p` prints the progress in %. Useful since it may take a while.

#### 3. Mount `image.vhd`

This can be done via file context menu or `diskmgmt.msc`, "Action → Attach VHD" menu item.

NTFS partitions of the disk will get letters assigned.

#### 4. Run `chkdsk`

Assuming `V:\` is the volume we need to check:

```
chkdsk V: /X /R
```

[`chkdsk` documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk).

This will take a lot of time.

#### 5. Done

That's it. Checked volume is remounted automatically and can be accessed. I can see the files that `testdisk` didn't find.

In case the damaged disk was a system disk and now accessed from a different/new Windows installation, it might be difficult to access user files due to ownership/permissions. But that's a different story.

Comment: Well done, I thought it would be impossible to do this, I thought you'd better just give up, but you actually did it!